# How to auto slide pages of .odp .pdf documents embedded using viewer.js

Tags: javascript, html, pdf.js

I have a website that has embedded .pdf and .odp documents using viewer.js. Embedding these documents was quite easy by following [viewer.js instructions here](https://viewerjs.org/instructions/). It outputs something like this[image: Output].
The problem is it opens documents in its own viewer with Presentation button in top right corner. I don't want this. I want like something like a bootstrap carousel. I want the pages of the documents to slide every 4-5 seconds and get rid of the everything else that is being displayed. Is this possible with viewer.js? If not what would be the best way of achieving what I want?

Comment: Hey there, did you find a solution for this? Thanks

Comment: i was able to do it for pdfs with pdf.js but i can not be sure about other files.